# error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token

Tags: ros, c++, rosmessage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there !

I try to compile a package that I found in the internet but I still get this error:

```
  In file included from /home/ros/rosbuildstaubli/staubli3/src/controller.cpp:14:0:
  /home/ros/rosbuildstaubli/staubli3/include/command.h: At global scope:
  /home/ros/rosbuildstaubli/staubli3/include/command.h:24:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
  /home/ros/rosbuildstaubli/staubli3/include/command.h:205:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
  /home/ros/rosbuildstaubli/staubli3/include/command.h: In constructor ‘staubli::command::Request::Request()’:
  /home/ros/rosbuildstaubli/staubli3/include/command.h:57:27: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
  /home/ros/rosbuildstaubli/staubli3/include/command.h:57:27: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
```

The class Request heritate from ros::Message and this is what cause the errors, each time I use:

> `class Request : public ros::Message`

This is the headers that I have in each those two files

[commande.h](http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Staubli/srv/cpp/staubli/command.h):

```
 #include <string>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <vector>
 #include <map>
 #include "ros/message.h"
 #include "ros/time.h"
```

[controller.cpp](http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Staubli/src/controller.cpp):

```
 #include "TX60L.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <ros/ros.h>
 #include <std_msgs/String.h>
 #include <sstream>
 #include "command.h"       //command service of staubli
 #include "controller.h"
```

I'm using ros-Hydro ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205378/error:-expected-class-name-before-%E2%80%98%7B%E2%80%99-token/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ros::Message` class appears to be deprecated and has been removed. From a quick look through the version history, it looks like it was removed some time before the Fuerte release.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-03-19**:
I'm using Hydro

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-03-19**:
It's usually a good idea to include your ROS distro in your questions. I checked the version history as far back as I was able to (Fuerte), and didn't find a version where the Message class was available.